# WordPress permalinks Issue on Localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, permalinks

I have this problem, so far i change or permalinks or delete .htaccess file and everything worked but this this this is not the issue. Have broken links on few link with 404 error. Home page i most of the links works but 3-4 of them don't. Tried so far everything that I thinks should work or worked before. Deleted .htaccess file, disable plugins and themes restore to default, change permalinks structure, my WAMP server have enabled rewrite module on for apache, even in htppd.conf have AllowOverride All.

I dont have any ideas left and I would appreciate if someone have some new idea or something that I have missed so far.

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching for the problem finally find it. It was conflict with plugin and my custom added css was conflict with one plugin same name and this was causing the issues on links.

Considering that I lost time for this i needed to share this info with all of you. Usually permalinks problems were solved with changing settings for permalinks but this was something else, and probably I'm the only one that have same name in css with one plugin and this cause the problem.

Hopefully this will help someone if come to same or similar issue.